# filename with space

Tags: shell

I have written a shell script which picks all the files recursively inside all the directories and prepared a report with the file last modified, size.
The problem that I am facing, there are few files with name as "User Interface"(space in between). How to use there files in the for loop of the shell script and fetch the files and directories inside this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the script you've been using.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the file name variable between double quotes `"$FILENAME"`

Answer (score 3):

You're probably trying to use something like `for file in $(command)`. Instead, use a `while read` loop or a `for` loop with globbing. Make sure you quote variables that contain filenamess.

```
#!/bin/sh
command | while read -r file
do
    something_with "$file"
done
```

or, in shells that support process substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r file
do
    something_with "$file"
done < <(command)
```

If you're simply iterating over a list of files:

```
for file in "$dir"/*
do
    something_with "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Search led me to [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html)